# How to implode an array to show it in a textbox in yii2 ActiveForm?

Tags: yii2, active-form

Children field is an array in mongoDB:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'children') ?>
```

The error I get is:

```
Array to string conversion
```

I need to use `implode(',', $model->children)` somehow, how to use it in an `ActiveForm`? What to do now?

What is the solution? How to turn that array into a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wanted to turn it into string in every widget, grid view and so I used `afterFind()` function in my model in order to convert it into string. Now everything seems awesome:

```
public function afterFind() {
        parent::afterFind();
        if (is_array($this->children)) {
            $this->children = implode(',', $this->children);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The content of the `$model->children` attribute is displayed when being used in a `$form->field()` call. If the content of the attribute is an array and you want/need it to be a string you'll have to convert the content before the `field()` call.

So like this, it will probably work.

```
<?php    
$model->children = implode(',', $model->children);
echo $form->field($model, 'children');
?>
```

Not sure editing a list value like this (in a textfield) is the best way. You'll have to explode the string back when saving. But the code above is the solution to turn that array into a string.

Comment: This workaround cause duplicate codes in different `views` file. I solved it by `afterFind()` in my core model in order to return string in the first place. 

+1 thanks.